# In python I've created a list

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x

```
mylist= [9, 'a', 'cat', False, 3.14, 7]

h = mylist.sort() 
print(mylist)
```

However the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

shows up! 
How am I to change the types to int so that the program can run succesfully.

Comment: What are you expecting as your result?

Comment: how do you want your `cat` and `a` converted to `int`?

Comment: I didnt get error in `Python 2.7`, `>>> mylist.sort()
>>> print mylist
[False, 3.14, 7, 9, 'a', 'cat']
`

Comment: Think about it. How would you compare number 9 to the letter "a"? Is "cat" bigger (>) than or smaller (<) than boolean value False? You can only order lists that contain comparable things. Numbers with numbers, letters with letters etc...

Comment: It can't be sorted in python3 but it can be done with python2

Answer (score 1):

## For [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)

The method `.sort()` and `sorted()` requires that the items in the iterable are of the same type.

```
>>> sorted([1, 2]) #Same
[1, 2]
>>> sorted([1, 'a']) #Different
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
>>> sorted(['b', 'a']) #Same
['a', 'b']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   mylist= [9, 'a', 'cat', False, 3.14, 7]
   h = sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: str(x))
   print(h)
```

you need str it and sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have several options to solve the problem:

1: Use a try to avoid your script to break

```
try:
    mylist.sort()
except TypeError:
    pass
print(mylist)
```

2: Convert everthing to string

```
new_list=[str(datum) for datum in mylist]
new_list.sort()
print(new_list)
```

3: Emulate the behavior of python2 sort implementation

4: Use python2